# Facebook comments on each post

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, sql

When i apply this query, it shows comments on every post, repeatedly:

```
"SELECT post.posttext,post.post_id,comment.comt_id 
FROM post FULL JOIN comment ON  post.post_id=comment.post_id 
AND user.user_id=".$userid."" ;
```

Comment: so what's your question?

Comment: congratulations

Comment: same comment show on every post

Comment: congratulations indeed. What's the question ?

Comment: MY QUESTION IS, When i apply this query it show me same comment on every post but i want comments like facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT post.posttext, post.post_id, comment.comt_id 
FROM post 
LEFT JOIN comment ON 
    post.post_id=comment.post_id AND user.user_id={$userid}
GROUP BY comment.comment_id ;
```

Comment: it sow me the error but i have user_id in the user table.

Comment: Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'user.user_id' in 'on clause'

SELECT post.posttext, post.post_id, comment.comt_id FROM post LEFT JOIN comment ON post.post_id=comment.post_id AND user.user_id=10 GROUP BY comment.comment_id

Filename: C:\wamp\www\SocialNetworking\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Comment: You must join user table as well I guess, or it must be `post.user_id`